# Commerce search: return products containing keywords in related entries' fields

Tags: entries, search, relations, plugin-craftcommerce3, products

Craft CMS 3.6.11.2 / Commerce 3.2.17.4

We have a `Stores` structure section that contains fields (searchable) such as phone, address, etc.  These `Stores` are assigned as `Entries` (searchable, max of 1) to `Commerce products`.

When searching for products with a keyword that matches a `Store` phone, address, etc,  none of these products are returned.

The search query is basic and as follows:

```
{% set search_query = '9999' %}
{% set products_query = craft.products.type('products').search(search_query) %}
```

So e.g., if `9999` is the phone number of a `Store` and we have `Products` that are assigned that `Store`, the search results return nothing.

Has anyone ever had this issue?  Is there a specific query that can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of relational fields, on the title of the related Assets/Categories/Entries is searchable.

As stated in the documentation:

> For Matrix fields, the top-level **Use this field’s values as search keywords** setting determines whether any sub-fields will factor into results for the parent. For relational fields like Assets, Categories, and Entries, the setting determines whether related titles should factor into search results.

Comment: Thank you Oli.  Just wondering whether the 'Use this field’s values as search keywords' setting will be taken for account for relational fields as well one of these days.  I can see this as a really powerful feature as we can't jam every single keyword into the title in most cases.